# Any identical replacement for zoom property?

Tags: html, css

Inherited a web project which frontend's desing heavily relies on css zoom property

```
body { zoom: 90%;}
```

Now, this is causing all kinds of problems on major browsers (except for chrome).

**transform: scale(0.9, 0.9)** doesn't do the trick as they work in different ways. Zoom property acts like browser's zoom in/zoom out functionality, while scale just, well, scales the content (and leaves empty space around the scaled element (and in the project zoom is put on body tag, thus entire page is zoomed out)).

Any identical replacement available for zoom property (supported by modern browsers) or I'm better off just adjusting each element's width/height and text size and removing zoom property entirely?

Comment: Wow. What a poorly-designed solution. You should rewrite it almost certainly.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone use `zoom` on the `body`.